# Hibernate oneToMany SQLGrammarException

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have two classes "Project" and "Report". A Project can contain any number of Reports. When I add the first Report to a Project everything is working fine.
But when I add another Report to a Project, and use the saveOrUpdate method on the Project, I get a SQLGrammarException!

I have already checked the names of the columns.

Project mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_PROJECT")
public class Project implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  @Column(name ="PROJECT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private int projectID;

  @Column(name = "NAME", unique = false, nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "CLIENT", unique = false, nullable = false)
  private String client;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name="PROJECT_REPORTS", joinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="PROJECT_ID", referencedColumnName="PROJECT_ID")}
      , inverseJoinColumns= {@JoinColumn(name="REPORT_ID", referencedColumnName="REPORT_ID")})
  private List<Report> reportList = new ArrayList<Report>();
```

Report mapping:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_REPORT", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "REPORT_ID") })
public class Report implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name ="REPORT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int reportID;

    @Column(name = "NAME", unique = false, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name ="AMOUNT_COMPONENTS")
    private int amountComponents;

    @Column(name ="AMOUT_ACCEPTED")
    private int amountAccepted;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_REJECTED")
    private int amountRejected;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_DRAFT")
    private int amountUnderDevelopment;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT_REVIEW")
    private int amountUnderReview;

    @Column(name = "TODELETE")
    private Boolean toDelete = false;
```

Hibernate:

```
@Override
    public void updatePersistentProject(Project project) {
        try {
            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(project);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        } catch (HibernateException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Console output:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into TB_REPORT (REPORT_ID, AMOUT_ACCEPTED, AMOUNT_COMPONENTS, AMOUNT_REJECTED, AMOUNT_DRAFT, AMOUNT_REVIEW, NAME, TODELETE) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update TB_PROJECT set CLIENT = ?, NAME = ?, TO_DELETE = ? where PROJECT_ID=?
Hibernate: update TB_REPORT set AMOUT_ACCEPTED = ?, AMOUNT_COMPONENTS = ?, AMOUNT_REJECTED = ?, AMOUNT_DRAFT = ?, AMOUNT_REVIEW = ?, NAME = ?, TODELETE = ? where REPORT_ID=?
Hibernate: update TB_REPORT set AMOUT_ACCEPTED = ?, AMOUNT_COMPONENTS = ?, AMOUNT_REJECTED = ?, AMOUNT_DRAFT = ?, AMOUNT_REVIEW = ?, NAME = ?, TODELETE = ? where REPORT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete PROJECT_REPORTS where PROJECT_ID=?

Juli 20, 2019 10:07:40 VORM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
Juli 20, 2019 10:07:40 VORM. org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: FEHLER: Syntaxfehler bei »PROJECT_REPORTS«
  Position: 8
Juli 20, 2019 10:07:40 VORM. org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete PROJECT_REPORTS where PROJECT_ID=?]]
Juli 20, 2019 10:07:40 VORM. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ReportServlet] in context with path [/project] threw exception
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete PROJECT_REPORTS where PROJECT_ID=?]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1436)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:487)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2786)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:1932)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:272)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:104)
    at dao.ProjectDAOImpl.updatePersistentProject(ProjectDAOImpl.java:70)
    at logic.ReportImpl.createReport(ReportImpl.java:39)
    at gui.ReportServlet.createReport(ReportServlet.java:223)
    at gui.ReportServlet.doGet(ReportServlet.java:64)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at gui.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete PROJECT_REPORTS where PROJECT_ID=?]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.execute(JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.execute(JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.execute(JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.collection.JoinTableRemovalExecutor.execute(JoinTableRemovalExecutor.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.spi.AbstractPersistentCollectionDescriptor.remove(AbstractPersistentCollectionDescriptor.java:1245)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionUpdateAction.execute(CollectionUpdateAction.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:474)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1430)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: Syntaxfehler bei »PROJECT_REPORTS«
  Position: 8
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2468)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:309)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.execute(JdbcMutationExecutorImpl.java:68)
    ... 49 more
```

Comment: Do you have set the correct hibernate dialect?